# How to auto split the data frame into years

Tags: r

I have attached a part of the data frame, I know how to manually sub set the data into just the years 1959 or 1969, but this data goes on from 1959 to 2003. Is there a way I can have it auto split it for every single year?

[image]

Comment: `dplyr::group_by()` is your friend!

Comment: Very often the functions have the proper name : `split(DF,DF$year)` (this returns a list of data.frame's, one for each year)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what tool(s) you're using for analysis you have a few options.

**base R** 
The `split` function takes one object (like a data frame) and a vector that defines the splits. It returns a list of the split results. Note in the example below my data.frame has 3 columns and I split by column `a`. The result is a named list of length 2, one for each unique value in `a`. Also note that I could split `df` by some other value not in the data.frame - when I pass in `df$a` I'm passing in a vector of the same length as the number of rows in my data.frame.

```
df = data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),b=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),c=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
split(df,df$a)

#> $`1`
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 1 1
#> 2 1 2 2
#> 3 1 3 3
#> 
#> $`2`
#>   a b c
#> 4 2 1 4
#> 5 2 2 5
#> 6 2 3 6
```

**tidyverse**

Using `dplyr` from the tidyverse, you could do analysis on your data by group. You could also filter out unwanted values first. See here how I first `filter` out the unwanted values (only keep where column `a` is equal to 1). You could accomplish this with something like `year %in% c(1959,1969)`. Then I specify a grouping column with `group_by` - now if I do something like change a column or fit a model, it will be done by the `b` column values. In your case, you would want to group by `year`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(a == 1) %>%
  group_by(b)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   b [3]
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     2     2
#> 3     1     3     3
```

**data.table**

You could look into using `data.table` with something like `df[year %in% c(1959,1969),AvgAve = mean(Ave),by=year]` (that syntax may not work perfectly) to calculate the average Ave by each year keeping only 1959 and 1969